# Relating two gradients to each other?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question asks to write the function $F(x, y, z) = e^{xyz}$ as a composition of the functions $f$ and $g$, and to relate the gradient of $f$ to the gradient of $g$. ($f$ has to be a one variable function and $g$ has to be a three variable function)

I chose $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=xyz$.

$\nabla f(x) = e^x$**i**

$\nabla g(x, y, z) = yz$**i**$+xz$**j**$+xy$**k**

However, I don't understand what relating the gradients to each other means. I don't see a way to write one gradient as a function of the other or anything like that.

Comment: Note that $\nabla f$,(or $f'$), is a scalar function. Try to relate$f'\nabla g$ with $\nabla F$.

Comment: @GitGud HM so $\nabla F = e^{yz} f' \nabla g$?

Comment: No. Let me apologize. I was imprecise in what I wanted to say and ended up giving misleading information.What I should have said is: try to relate $\left(f'\circ g\right)\nabla g$ with $\nabla F$, noting that $f'\circ g$ is a scalar function of three variables(so the product makes sense)..

Comment: @GitGud Hm so then they are just equal to each other. But why do we prefer the second relationship over the first one?

Comment: @Ovi GitGud's point is that $\nabla f=f'\nabla g$.  That is the relationship regardless of the choice of composition $f(g(x,y,z))$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Not sure what you mean, $e^x =/= e^x \nabla g$ and $\nabla F =/= e^x \nabla g$ as well.

Comment: $F=f(g(x,y,z))$.  Then, $\nabla F=\nabla f(g(x,y,z))=f'(g(x,y,z))\nabla g(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.